# Can't create .zip file with Azure Logic Apps' SharePoint Create File action

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create a .zip file by passing the returned body of an HTTP GET request to SharePoint's Create File.

Body is:

```
{
  "$content-type": "application/zip",
  "$content": "UEsDBBQACA...="
}
```

Shouldn't this just work? The docs only define the Create File field as "Content of the file." but that's not super informative...

I believe I've done this before with a file that was `application/pdf` and it worked. Unfortunately, I can't find that Logic App (I think it may have been an experiment I've since deleted).

I should note that the Create File action *does* create a valid .zip file, in that it's not corrupt, but archive is empty. It's supposed to contain a single .csv file.

I tried decoding the Base64 content and it's definitely binary data.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I test with Postman and when I use the `form-data` way to POST the request, I found the .zip file couldn't be open. Then I check the Logic App run history and I find the problem is if just use the `triggerbody()` as the file content it will fail.

This is because the `triggerbody()` not just have the `$content`, so I change the expression to `triggerBody()['$multipart'][0]['body']` then it works and the .zip file is full.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe the file I am being given by the 3rd party is the problem. Using 7-Zip File Manager I am able to open the ZIP to see that there is an unnamed folder wrapping the CSV file I'm trying to get. So when Windows opens the ZIP and I see an empty directory it's because it doesn't know what to do with the unnamed folder. 7-Zip is a little more flexible and lets me open that folder to find the file I'm looking for. Unless you have another idea, I don't think there's anything I can do but contact them to see if they will fix this.